# After scanning popup window android

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to add a popup like this in my app in android after I scan a HR code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 NiftyDialogBuilder dialogBuilder=NiftyDialogBuilder.getInstance(this);
    // Effectstype effect = null;
    Dialog v = null;
    dialogBuilder
            .withTitle("Modal Dialog")                                  //.withTitle(null)  no title
            .withTitleColor("#FFFFFF")                                  //def
            .withDividerColor("#11000000")                              //def
            .withMessage("This is a modal Dialog.")                     //.withMessage(null)  no Msg
            .withMessageColor("#FFFFFFFF")                              //def  | withMessageColor(int resid)
            .withDialogColor("#FFE74C3C")                               //def  | withDialogColor(int resid)
            .withIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.baba))
            .withDuration(700)                                          //def
            // .withEffect(effect)                                         //def Effectstype.Slidetop
            .withButton1Text("OK")                                      //def gone
            .withButton2Text("Cancel")                                  //def gone
            .isCancelableOnTouchOutside(true)                           //def    | isCancelable(true)
            //.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_view,v.getContext())         //.setCustomView(View or ResId,context)
            .setButton1Click(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "i'm btn1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .setButton2Click(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"i'm btn2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .show();
```